# Finding bright spots in a image using opencv

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, image-segmentation, scikit-image

[image: This is the image in which I want to find the bright spots and tag them.]

I want to find the bright spots in the above image and tag them using some symbol. For this i have tried using the **Hough Circle Transform** algorithm that OpenCV already provides. But it is giving some kind of assertion error when i run the code. I also tried the **Canny edge detection** algorithm which is also provided in OpenCV but it is also giving some kind of assertion error. I would like to know if there is some method to get this done or if i can prevent those error messages.

I am new to OpenCV and any help would be really appreciated.

P.S. - I can also use Scikit-image if necessary. So if this can be done using Scikit-image then please tell me how.

Below is my preprocessing code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np



image = cv2.imread("image1.png")

gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

binary_image = np.where(gray_image > np.mean(gray_image),1.0,0.0)

binary_image = cv2.Laplacian(binary_image, cv2.CV_8UC1)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are just going to work with simple images like your example where you have black background, you can use same basic preprocessing/thresholding then find connected components. Use this example code to draw a circle inside all circles in the image.

```
import cv2 
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread("image1.png")

#  constants
BINARY_THRESHOLD = 20
CONNECTIVITY = 4
DRAW_CIRCLE_RADIUS = 4

#  convert to gray
gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

#  extract edges
binary_image = cv2.Laplacian(gray_image, cv2.CV_8UC1)

#  fill in the holes between edges with dilation
dilated_image = cv2.dilate(binary_image, np.ones((5, 5)))

#  threshold the black/ non-black areas
_, thresh = cv2.threshold(dilated_image, BINARY_THRESHOLD, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

#  find connected components
components = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(thresh, CONNECTIVITY, cv2.CV_32S)

#  draw circles around center of components
#see connectedComponentsWithStats function for attributes of components variable
centers = components[3]
for center in centers:
    cv2.circle(thresh, (int(center[0]), int(center[1])), DRAW_CIRCLE_RADIUS, (255), thickness=-1)

cv2.imwrite("res.png", thresh)
cv2.imshow("result", thresh)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Here is resulting image:
[image: Picture showing drawn circles inside found connected components]

Edit: connectedComponentsWithStats takes a binary image as input, and returns connected pixel groups in that image. If you would like to implement that function yourself, naive way would be:
1- Scan image pixels from top left to bottom right until you encounter a non-zero pixel that does not have a label (id).
2- When you encounter a non-zero pixel, search all its neighbours recursively( If you use 4 connectivity you check UP-LEFT-DOWN-RIGHT, with 8 connectivity you also check diagonals) until you finish that region. Assign each pixel a label. Increase your label counter.
3- Continue scanning from where you left.

Comment: Why not show off your results? People like illustrated answers and they are easy to understand and check...

Comment: Sorry, I completely agree. Attached an example picture as you suggested.

Comment: I pretty much understood the code but I did not get what the "connectedComponentsWithStats" function actually do?

Comment: It takes a binary image as input, and returns connected pixel groups in that image. If you would like to implement that function yourself, naive way would be:  
1- Scan image pixels from top left to bottom right until you encounter a non-zero pixel that does not have a label (id).
2- When you encounter a non-zero pixel, search all its neighbours recursively( If you use 4 connectivity you check UP-LEFT-DOWN-RIGHT, with 8 connectivity you also check diagonals) until you finish that region. Assign each pixel a label. Increase your label counter.
3- Continue scanning from where you left.

Comment: Also is there a way I could create grid lines around those circles such that each circle should be inside the grid box?

Comment: As I said, you can check output of connectedComponentsWithStats function, it returns information like top left (x, y) coordinate of found components, width of component, height of component, center of component ..., you can use those and [opencv draw functions](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html).

Comment: Thank you so much. It is a great answer!