# Detecting Glare in image

Tags: ios, swift, opencv, image-processing, core-image

I am adding a card scanning feature to my iOS app and trying to add glare detection. So when a glare is detected while scanning, user is prompted to reposition the card.

I have tried implementing it with OpenCV using 
https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/10/31/detecting-multiple-bright-spots-in-an-image-with-python-and-opencv/

https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/09/29/finding-brightest-spot-image-using-python-opencv/

[Finding bright spots in a image using opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51846933/finding-bright-spots-in-a-image-using-opencv)

But considering I have very less background knowledge in OpenCV and computer vision, I am unable to get desired results.

Kindly guide me in right direction on how can I achieve glare detection using OpenCV/CoreImage/GPUImage.

My code so far

```
+ (bool) imageHavingGlare:(CMSampleBufferRef)buffer {
 cv::Mat matImage = [OpenCVWrapper matFromBuffer:buffer];
 cv::Mat matImageGrey;
 cv::cvtColor(matImage, matImageGrey, CV_BGRA2GRAY);

 GaussianBlur(matImageGrey, matImageGrey, cvSize(11,11), 0);

 cv::Mat matImageBinarized;
 cv::threshold(matImageGrey, matImageBinarized, 30, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY | CV_THRESH_OTSU);

 double min, max;
 cv::Point min_loc, max_loc;
 cv::minMaxLoc(matImageBinarized, &min, &max, &min_loc, &max_loc);    

 if(((max_loc.x > 0) && (max_loc.y > 0)))
 {
    return true;
 }

 return false;
}
```

Comment: Can you add an example of glare in an image you are trying to detect?

Comment: show us your code

Comment: I have added my code @user1241241

Comment: simply use Laplacian to detect how blurry the frame is and prompt the user accordingly